# Bloomberg API Corporate actions export in C#

Tags: c#, bloomberg

Currently at my workplace we export Bloomberg Dividends manually. I would like to automate the process to make it a little easier for our team. Idea is, from the corporate actions I need to grab dividends, splits, M & A, and listings for a specific date. So far I've seen conflicting answers as to whether this is possible or not. If it is, how would I request such data?

Comment: Sounds like more of a question for Bloomberg Support

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that exists. To my knowledge you can only extract via API fields such as BDP BDH BDS BTH and eventually BEQS.

Create a portfolio via BBU, then exctracting in CACT as xls is quite easy.